# Azure DevOps pipeline trigger does not fire

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

#### Problem

Azure DevOps has a feature (documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#pipeline-triggers-1)) to trigger a pipeline on completion from another pipeline.
This works fine in a test organization, but it won't work in our main organization.
There could be something on the organization, project, repository or even branching level, but I'm currently stuck and any help would be appreciated!

#### Pipelines

Pipeline `Pipeline B` should run automatically when pipeline `Pipeline A` completes.

File `pipeline-a.yaml` for `Pipeline A`:

```
pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
- script: echo Hello, world!
  displayName: 'Do something'
```

File `pipeline-b.yaml` for `Pipeline B`:

```
trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

resources: 
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: pipeline-a
    source: 'Pipeline A'
    branch: master
    trigger: 
      branches:
      - master

steps:
- script: echo Hello, world!
  displayName: 'Do something'
```

#### Organizations

In my test organization the above pipelines run like a charm. This means that `Pipeline A` runs on a commit, and after completion, `Pipeline B` runs automatically.

Yet in our production organization, `Pipeline B` does not run automatically.

#### Discovery

- Both pipelines run fine when started manually, in both organizations
- All Preview features are equal on organization and personal level for both organizations, including the *Multi-stage pipelines* feature.
- The production organization has branch policies on master, while the test organization does not have policies. I don't see a connection with pipeline triggers and did not investigate this.
- Installing extensions to have them equal on test and production does not make a difference.
- The test organization seems to be in the [slow ring](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/learn/devops-at-microsoft/release-flow) and was still on Sprint 161. EDIT: The issue persists after the organization was updated to Sprint 162.
- It works when I use the classic editor and manually create a *build completion trigger*. But this overrides the YAML pipeline trigger and I don't want to do this (I want to generate the pipeline and it's triggers)

Comment: I try to reproduce your setting. Just a quick question: Are both pipelines "Release" pipelines or do you mean by CI/CD that "CI = Build" and "CD = Release"?

Comment: Another question: Are both pipelines created as YAML file or with the classical editor?

Comment: @Jonas: They're both YAML pipelines. The CI/CD distinction is about the functional application and not relevant to the technical issue at hand. I edited the description.

Comment: Ok, I reproduced the setting and I face the same behavior as in your test orga - everything works fine. B gets automatically triggered by the completion of A. Just another question to clarify: You said that all preview features are the same including the _Multi-stage pipelines_ feature. What is the actual status of this feature? Is it enabled or disabled on both organizations?

Comment: I have only one idea what the cause of your problem could be.
In your production organization please open `Pipelines` > At **Pipeline B** Click `Edit` from the 3-dot-menu on the right side > Click `Triggers` at 3-dot-menu at the top-right-corner > Ensure the _Override the YAML continuous integration trigger from here_ option is not checked.

Comment: @Jonas: Thnx. _Multi-stage pipelines_ feature is enabled in both orgs. There is no YAML trigger override in the front-end (front-end was only used to name the pipelines). Also, the test org was on the slow ring and is now on Sprint 162 too. This didn't introduce the issue, so seems not related to this sprint.

Comment: I am sorry but for now I don't see the cause of the problem...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Deleting and re-adding the pipeline did the trick. So keep the YAML file but delete the pipeline and add it again.

The Azure DevOps backend seems to miss a relationship between pipelines now and then.

Comment: As of today Pipeline APIs  are still in preview. Sometimes unpredictable scenarios like this happens. If using the web UI these kind of scenarios happening due to browser caching.

Comment: I did this today. I have multiple pipelines and as per the above example let pipeline a, x, y, z. my pipeline-b is triggering if any one of the pipeline pass. So I deleted my pipeline-a and recreated it with the same name. The trigger is not working for pipeline-a now but works for x, y z. Do I want to delete & recreate pipeline-b also?

Answer (score 8):

We troubleshot a similar problem today. With `Pipeline-A` defined as a resource that is meant to be consumed by `Pipeline-B`.

The consuming pipeline was never being triggered. Deleting and recreating the pipeline did not work for us. This work\pipeline was net new and on a feature branch. That ended up being important.

The ultimate fix was defining that feature branch as the `Default branch for manual and scheduled builds` in `Pipeline-B`. You can find that setting tucked away in `Pipeline -> Edit -> triggers -> yaml-> Get Sources`. Expect that as we promote this code to the main branch we will need to update the setting.

So it seems like the *Default branch for manual and scheduled builds* would be better named

*Default branch for manual and scheduled builds and Pipeline Completion Triggers*

Comment: This is exactly the problem we had. However, when I ran Pipeline-A from master in my case, it did not trigger Pipeline-B. I assumed that's because it picks up the branch Pipeline-A was run from, and the yaml pipeline doesn't exist on master. But then I should be able to run Pipeline-A from my feature branch (with the default for B still set to master), but that doesn't work either. Running A from the feature branch with B's default also on the feature branch worked though.

Comment: Thanks! This interface with the combination of the WebUI and the YAML files and kind of unreliable and poorly documented integrations in general are not fun to deal with, but this helped me get my automated triggers to work while the work is in a development branch and was able to write a clear guide for the team to reconfigure this after PR merge 

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was as simple as the source pipeline completing with an error. Testing with a very simple non erroring pipeline and the code worked fine.